# nba_api timeouts when run with GitHub workflow

Tags: python, timeout, github-actions, nba-api

I use npa_api requests to get play-by-play data for some games.
The request works on my personal computer with python environment:

**leaguegamefinder.LeagueGameFinder(player_or_team_abbreviation='T',date_from_nullable = Today,date_to_nullable = Today, league_id_nullable = '00', outcome_nullable = "W")**

But I want to run my python code with the workflow tool of Github and, in that case, it gives me the following error:

**requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stats.nba.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=30)**

I have seen that NBA API blacklists the request from some cloud hosting providers but I did not find a solution to pass this block (using different proxies or new headers does not seem to solve the prob) and I don't know if there is one though.

Does anybody have an idea about this kind of problem?
Thanks a lot!